# Android Network Problem - wired ethernet passes ICMP pings OK but can't make TCP connections? When connected to 2 networks doesn't use right one

Tags: android, networking, tcp, icmp

Android tablet is configured with a wired ethernet connection (via USB hub) to a router w/out internet connectivity, and also connects to a WLAN from a different router, on which it can get internet. In this configuration we'll get good internet connection, can ping the router (and other devices on its LAN), but can't make TCP connections to/through the router, e.g., pull up the router's web page. (There's no address collision between the networks.)

The connections all work (except the internet of course) if we put the tablet on the router's WiFi.
I'm also told (but won't be able to test until tomorrow) that connecting the router's empty WAN port to an internet-connected wired LAN enables Android connections to the router's LAN.

Some issue with how Android routes when a connection has no internet?
Under what circumstances would an ICMP ping work but no TCP connection is possible? (Doesn't seem to be a MSS/MTU sort of issue.)

EDIT: noticed that traceroute indeed shows packets intended for the wired router dying on the wireless router.

Specifically, Android shows

Enet: IP 192.168.8.239  Gateway 192.168.8.1  Mask 255.255.255.0

WiFi: IP 10.2.234.131  Gateway 10.2.234.1  Mask 255.255.255.0

But it looks like Android only has one "network" active at a time. And both networks have routing rules that send all traffic their way. I'd like to specify a routing rule that crosses interfaces, like set the Wifi net as active and add a route like 192.168.8.0/24 -> eth0: 0.0.0.0, but docs say it will throw an IllegalArgumentException if I add a route with a different interface.

Only alternative I see is switching the active network back and forth between CAPABILITY_INTERNET and TRANSPORT_ETHERNET and trying to organize the apps traffic such that there's never any overlap in time??

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

I'll mark this as an answer even though there are still aspects of Android's network behavior in this circumstance that I still don't understand.

As guessed above, Android is only permitting one of the 2 networks to be active at any given time. I haven't found a detailed accounting of the metrics the system uses to decide which network to rely upon at any given time, though clearly in my example the absence of internet connectivity as determined by Android plays a role in the system's reluctance to use the hardwired internet connection. System APIs do permit an app to force use of a particular network, so in the above scheme requesting a TRANSPORT_ETHERNET network can force the app onto the hardwired connection. But the fundamental answer of whether Android can maintain simultaneous TCP connections over a device's WiFi & ethernet appears to be: NO.

The remaining question is why does ICMP ping work on an inactive Android network that won't host a TCP connection. Perhaps activation is mediated at the transport layer so that inactive interfaces that could wake up at any moment appear consistently alive to connected devices?